# truffle-hdWallet-provider not return correact address when using private key

Tags: web3js, truffle

I want to access MyEtherWallet account address from [truffle-hdwallet-provider](https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle-hdwallet-provider).

This is the code.

```

```
var HDWalletProvider = require("truffle-hdwallet-provider");
var privateKey = process.env.KEY;
var infuraApiKey = process.env.INFURA;

module.exports = {
  // See <http://truffleframework.com/docs/advanced/configuration>
  // to customize your Truffle configuration!
  networks: {
    development: {
      host: "127.0.0.1",
      port: 7545,
      network_id: "*"
    },
    mainnet: {
      provider: function () {
        return new HDWalletProvider(
          privateKey,
          "https://mainnet.infura.io/" + infuraApiKey
        );
      },
      network_id: 1,
      gas: 2000000,
      gasPrice: 3000000000 // 3 Gwei
    }
  }
};
```

```

In process.env.KEY, there are correct private key.
It is correct because I can access my account using this private key.

However, I run `truffle console --network mainnet` and chek my address `web3.eth.getAccounts(function(err, res){console.log(res)})`, it returns wrong address.

Why??

The private key is correct, but I can't access another address I don't know.
Why??

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The same for me.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with `truffle-hdwallet-provider@1.0.0-web3one.0`. 
Upgrade to `truffle-hdwallet-provider@1.0.8` solved the problem.